# ActionBar, Tabs, Fragments and Navigation

Tags: navigation, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android

I wonder if anyone has any experience hooking up an `ActionBar` with `Tabs`, `Fragments` and ancestral navigation (i.e. drill-down)? I've managed to put together an `ActionBar` with `Tabs` and `Fragments` using the app icon as the 'up' button... but the only means of navigation between `Fragments` seems to be by implementing my own backstacks for each tab and using `FragmentManager` to pop and add `Fragments`.

What I really would like to know is - is this the best way of doing this or is there a better / design pattern to follow?

Thanks!